# Reducing execution time without compromising on accuracy and precision

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning

I have the following `NDSolve` code, and it is extremely time consuming for me to run it, even when I set both `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` to very low numbers such as 3 or 4. Moreover, when I set them at such values, the accuracy and the precision of the result will be compromised greatly, to the extent where my final result is nowhere near what I actually predicted.

The code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
z[t_] := y[t] - l Cos[φ[t]];
n[t_] := k Abs[z[t]]^(3/2) - c z'[t];
R = 0.0238;
k = 141000000;
c = 20;
g = 9.81;
μk = 0.1804;
i = 6*10^-6;
m = 0.035;
l = R Sqrt[2 (1 + Sin[-(1/2) π - 2*0.3])];


NDSolve[{
  m y''[t] == n[t] - m g,
  φ''[
    t] == (n[t]*l*Sin[φ[t]] + 
      m x''[t]*l*Cos[φ[t]])/i,
  
  x''[t] ==
   If[Abs[(x'[t] + l*φ'[t])] < 10^-6 // Evaluate, 
    l (φ''[
          t] Cos[φ[t]] - φ'[t]^2 Sin[φ[
           t]]) // Evaluate, 
    Evaluate@
     If[x'[t] + l*φ'[t] > 0, -μk*n[t]/m // 
       Evaluate, μk*n[t]/m // Evaluate]],
  
  y[0] == l*Cos[0.3], 
  y'[0] == -2.22, φ[0] == 0.3, φ'[0] == -56, 
  x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[z[t] == 0 // Evaluate, "StopIntegration"; Print[y'[t]]; 
   Print[φ'[t]]]}, {y'[t], y[t], x[t], 
  x'[t], φ[t], φ'[t], z[t], 
  n[t], φ''[t]}, {t, 0, 0.2}, 
 Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
   "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
 WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, MaxSteps -> 100000000, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 5]
```

In the nested `If` statement, I wrote `If[Abs[(x'[t] + l*φ'[t])] < 10^-6 // Evaluate` instead of `If[(x'[t] + l*φ'[t]) ==0 // Evaluate` (which is what I actually wanted) where `10^-6` is used as an approximation. It would be good if I can make this number as close to 0 as possible.

In conclusion, is there any method that I can possibly use, to optimise the code and reduce its execution time without compromising on its accuracy and precision? Thank you so much.

Comment: The nonlinear coupling of `x''[t] , \[CurlyPhi]''[t]`seems to be the main problem for `NDSolve`. Where does it come from? Some kind of a friction model?

Comment: yes. It is a piecewise thing for static and kinetic friction @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: @ bobthelegend Do you know the friction model described in the `WhenEvent` -documentation of Mathematica? This model works quite well without switching between the second order derivatives(thereby changing the ode structure) and is very useful!

Comment: Yea I have seen that before, but I can't seem to get the code to work. I think that's just because of my lack of skills and knowledge haha @UlrichNeumann

Comment: @MichaelE2, it should be angular velocity

Comment: Oh sorry did you mean `\[Phi][t]`?
 it should be 0.3. @MichaelE2

Comment: @bobthelegend: I tried to run your code but it doesn't finish. As far as I understand `x[t],y[t]` describe the motion of a pendulum with angle `\[CurlyPhi][t]`. Where does friction occur?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Please take a look at the code again, maybe when you copy pasted the code something wrong happened. (copying code into mathematica has always been quite glitchy for me) My code provided `phi'[t]==-56` instead of `phi''[t]==-56`. Thanks

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, it is in fact describing some sort of inverted pendulum, with a spring at one end. the friction occurs between the spring and the pendulum.

Comment: Thanks. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Speed tips:

- Explicit is faster than implicit.
- `"DiscontinuityProcessing"` is your friend.

Other tips:

- `WhenEvent` is mysterious sometimes, but not here.
- Functions should depend only on their arguments (best practice).
- If `1/10^6` is to be a significant value to `NDSolve`, `AccuracyGoal` probably has be somewhat larger than `6`.

Irrelevent, gratuitous tips:

- I hate curly phi. :)
- I hope I didn't break anything in refactoring.  (Maybe not irrelevant. We'll see.)

Some slight refactoring of the OP's code before converting it to an explicit ODE:

```
R = 0.0238;
k = 141000000;
c = 20;
g = 9.81;
μk = 0.1804;
i = 6*10^-6;
m = 0.035;
l = R Sqrt[2 (1 + Sin[-(1/2) π - 2*f])];
f = 0.223;

With[{nt = n[z[y[t], phi[t]], D[z[y[t], phi[t]], t]]},
  odeOP = {m y''[t] == nt - m g
    , phi''[t] ==
     1/i (nt l Sin[phi[t]] + m x''[t] l Cos[phi[t]])
    , x''[t] ==
     Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@If[
        Abs[x'[t] + l phi'[t]] < 1/10^6
        , l (phi''[t] Cos[phi[t]] - phi'[t]^2 Sin[phi[t]])
        , -If[x'[t] + l phi'[t] >= 0, 1, -1] (μk nt)/m
        ]}
  ];
```

Redefine `n[]`, `z[]`.  Differentiate to convert to explicit ODEs.  Handle the nondifferentiable functions like `Abs` and `UnitStep`.  Use `odeOP` above to fill in missing initial conditions for `x''[0]` and `phi''[0]`.  `NDSolve` automatically converts `If`, `Piecewise`, `UnitStep` to discrete events, but I did one of them manually (`sgn[t]`).  I usually don't like `Print` statements because they can fill a notebook and wrest control from you, if they unexpectedly get out of hand.  But I wanted a quick way to check whether an event was detected.

```
ClearAll[z, n];
z[y_, phi_] := y - l Cos[phi];
n[z_, zp_] := k Abs[z]^(3/2) - c zp;

With[{nt = n[z[y[t], phi[t]], D[z[y[t], phi[t]], t]]},
 odes = {m y''[t] == nt - m g
     , phi'''[t] == D[
       1/i (nt l Sin[phi[t]] + m x''[t] l Cos[phi[t]]) /. 
          {UnitStep -> us, Abs -> abs},
       t]
     , x'''[t] == D[
       Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@If[
           -(1/10^6) < x'[t] + l phi'[t] < 1/10^6
           , l (phi''[t] Cos[phi[t]] - phi'[t]^2 Sin[phi[t]])
           , -sgn[t] (μk nt)/m
           ] /. {UnitStep -> us, Abs -> abs},
       t]
     } /. {us'[_] -> 0, abs' -> (2 UnitStep[#] - 1 &), sgn'[t] -> 0} /.
    {us -> UnitStep, abs -> Abs};
 ics = {y[0] == l Cos[f]
   , y'[0] == -2.22
   , phi[0] == f
   , phi'[0] == -56
   , x[0] == 0
   , x'[0] == 0
   };
 ics = Join[ics, odeOP[[2 ;; 3]] /. t -> 0 /. First@Solve[ics]];
 ics = Join[ics, 
   sgn[0] == Sign[x'[t] + l phi'[t]] /. t -> 0 /. Solve[ics]];
 evts = {WhenEvent[z[y[t], phi[t]] == 0,
    {Print["Stopping at ", t]; "StopIntegration"}]
   , WhenEvent[x'[t] + l phi'[t] > -1/10^6,
    {Print["1" -> {InputForm@t, x'[t] + l phi'[t]}];
     x''[t] -> l (phi''[t] Cos[phi[t]] - phi'[t]^2 Sin[phi[t]])}]
   , WhenEvent[x'[t] + l phi'[t] < -1/10^6,
    {Print["2" -> {InputForm@t, x'[t] + l phi'[t]}];
     x''[t] -> -sgn[t] (μk nt)/m}]
   , WhenEvent[x'[t] + l phi'[t] > 1/10^6,
    {Print["3" -> {InputForm@t, x'[t] + l phi'[t]}];
     x''[t] -> -sgn[t] (μk nt)/m}]
   , WhenEvent[x'[t] + l phi'[t] < 1/10^6,
    {Print["4" -> {InputForm@t, x'[t] + l phi'[t]}];
     x''[t] -> l (phi''[t] Cos[phi[t]] - phi'[t]^2 Sin[phi[t]])}]
   , WhenEvent[x'[t] + l phi'[t] == 0,
    {Print["5" -> {InputForm@t, x'[t] + l phi'[t]}];
     sgn[t] -> -sgn[t]}]};
 ]
```

Run `NDSolve`. The monitor is something I use when code takes a long time to run, but it turns out not to be necessary with the `"StiffnessSwitching"` method.  Use the `Automatic` method, and you can see the stiffness develop just after `t = 0.001`.

```
PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{Clock@Infinity, foo};
sol = NDSolve[{odes, ics, evts}
    , {x, y, phi, sgn}
    , {t, 0, 0.2}
    , Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"
    , AccuracyGoal -> 13, (* Note a high AccuracyGoal is needed *)
    WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 5, StepMonitor :> (foo = t), 
    DiscreteVariables -> {sgn}, 
    MaxStepFraction -> 1/1000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> 1->{0.00014391781504231857, -1.*10^-6}  
> 5->{0.00014391792439061524, 1.19071*10^-14}  
> 3->{0.00014391803373883832, 1.*10^-6}
> ```
>
> Stopping at 0.000385506
>
> ```
> (* {0.085515, Null}  *)
> ```

```
Plot[##, PlotLegends -> {1000, 10, 1} {x, y, phi}] & @@
 {{10000, 10, 1} Through[{x, y, phi}[t]] /. First@sol, 
  Flatten@{t, x@"Domain" /. sol}}
```

> [image]

Check events:

```
Plot @@ {z[y[t], phi[t]] /. First@sol, Flatten@{t, x@"Domain" /. sol}}
Plot @@ {x'[t] + l phi'[t] /. First@sol, Flatten@{t, x@"Domain" /. sol}}
Plot @@ {sgn[t] /. First@sol, Flatten@{t, x@"Domain" /. sol}}
```

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

The second one, `x'[t] + l phi'[t]`, controls the `If[]` statement in the OP (converted to `WhenEvent`s) and `sgn[t]` and leads to events when its value  is `±1/10^6` or `0`.  The quantity is changing so fast that one wonders if all the events are detected, which was verified by the `Print` statements in the events.  The third plot shows that the sign change in `sgn[t]` is detected. Here is a visualization of the events. The so-called "signal" is the sign of the event `Abs[x'[t] + l phi'[t]] - 1/10^6 == 0` from the `If[]` statement in the OP's ODE system.

```
Plot[
 {2/1000000000, 1/2000, 1, 1} {x''[t], x''[t], sgn[t], 
     Sign[Abs[x'[t] + l phi'[t]] - 1/10^6]} /. First@sol // Evaluate,
 {t, 0.00014391775, 0.00014391815},
 PlotPoints -> 200, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness@Medium, Thickness@Medium, Directive[Thick], 
   Directive[Dashed, Thick]},
 PlotLegends -> {2./1000000000, 1./2000, 1, 1} {x'', x'', sgn, signal}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful :)

Comment: Hi, may I know how long did you take to run the code? The code has been running for around 20 minutes for me and it is not loading. Thank you @MichaelE2

Comment: The timing in the post is `0.085515` sec.  You changed the code from what it was in the beginning, which is what I worked from.  You might have to update it, since `f` seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Oh great!. I added `f=0.3;` at the front and the code worked. Thank you so much

Comment: @MichaelE2 Great answer! Could you  run the original code of the OP for comparison?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I aborted it after a few minutes.